# How to make button restriction?

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

[image: image of the problem]

Hello,
Could you please help me about coding in swift ? I'd like an user if tap X user will not have a chance to tap another buttons except "Y" ones.

Comment: have you tried something..

Comment: @galec Did you find a solution that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `enabled` (Swift 2) / `isEnabled` (Swift 3) property of the buttons to block the ones you don't want to be pressed.